# How to cut a file in this way?

Tags: command-line

I have to cut a long file (approx. 2 millions of lines) at the line that follows the line at which there is the last appearance of a word.

For example the file could be:

```
line 1
line 2 
....
word
line n
word
line n+2
```

This file should be cut at the second appearance of *word*, so the lines following *line n+2* (and that line too) should be dropped.

The problem is that I do not know in advance the number of times *word* appears in the file.

Comment: @bac0n Thanks that did the trick

Comment: @bac0n you seem to have written your answer in the comments section by mistake